# How do I install ubuntu without losing data?

Tags: 12.10

I have windows 7 currently installed on my C: drive , which is the only available drive. I want to insall ubuntu 12.10 withour deleting Windows 7 or ANY OF MY DATA. Do I need to partition my drive? Out of 320GB space I have only 48 GB free space on C: drive, and I don't want to lose any data. Also, will there be issues with drivers if have both Windows and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to askubuntu.You can use gparted which is included in Ubuntu Live CD to resize C Drive and make free space. Create Drive from that and have Ubuntu.

Comment: You can repartition, I do that all the time. Plus wubi depends on windows and is slower.

Comment: Are you talking about resizing is possible with Gparted ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I used to have dualboots, in which I had to resize the partitions. I would set up a new drive(no partitions) let windows install(entire disk) and resize after that for ubuntu. Why wouldn't that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a separate partition to put Ubuntu in, or install via wubi.

wubi is easier, as it installs it as if it where a Windows program, it also means you can easily keep all your data.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: wubi is slow + depents on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a part of the 48gb to make partitions for ubuntu without losing data.
There is an partition option while installing.
And Drivers for windows are only for windows, there is a seperation between them.
So you can install ubuntu without losing any data.

The easiest way to partition, is to shrink a part of the main partition(remove free area).
One you format as ext4, select as `/` mountpoint, and you make a second partition with the size of 1,5 times your ram, this will be your swap partition.

And you should now have 1 windows partition, 1 ext4 partition, and 1 swap partition.
Check whatever everything is like how you want it